# Запуск ASP.NET Core как фонового процесса на Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core

Здраствуйте, по следующему [гайду](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#monitor-the-app) запускаю приложение asp.net core в фоновом процессе. Но при выполнении команды `sudo systemctl status asp.service` выводится следующее сообщение:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of asp.service changed on disk. Run 

    'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
    ● asp.service - Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/asp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-07-27 16:16:34 UTC; 9min ago
      Process: 24639 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet ~/var/www/asptest/WebVm.dll (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
     Main PID: 24639 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
```

Вот код из файла asp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/asptest
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/asptest/WebVm.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=ubuntu
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Из под пользователя ubuntu производилась вся работа
Все каталоги созданы, и даже если запускать приложение командой: `/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/asptest/WebVm.dll`, то приложение запускается

Comment: У вас в сообщении об ошибке сервиса `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet ~/var/www/asptest/WebVm.dll` -- тильда перед `/var`. Вы уверены, что обновили `.service` файл? Сделайте `systemctl daemon-reload`